# NLog only email if a specific error occurs below a amount of time

Tags: .net, email, wrapper, nlog

Is there a way within the wrapper to avoid NLog email a specific error occurs below a amount of time?

Guy

Comment: Could you please add an example?

Comment: @Guy, do you want to skip duplicate messages? Check out [WhenRepeated filter](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WhenRepeated-Filter).